# VB.NET Insert DataGridView contents into Database

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

**Problem:**

I need to dump the contents of my DataGridView into a SQL Server Database Table.  I've got the datagridview loading fine, no problems there.  I'm just not familiar enough with VB.NET to understand how to get that data into a DB table.

**Code: (so far)**

```
    Dim connection As New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    Dim dataAdapter As New Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    Dim command As New Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    Dim dataSet As New Data.DataSet

    connection.ConnectionString = "Server= server; Database= DB; integrated security=true"
    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO <table> (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4) VALUES (@Name, @Property, @Value, @Date)"

    dataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@ServerName", SqlDbType.VarChar)
    dataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Property", SqlDbType.VarChar)
    dataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Value", SqlDbType.VarChar)
    dataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@CaptureDate", SqlDbType.DateTime)

    For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView.Rows.Count - 1
        dataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters(0).Value = dgvServerConfig.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value
        dataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters(1).Value = dgvServerConfig.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value
        dataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters(2).Value = dgvServerConfig.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value
        dataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters(3).Value = dgvServerConfig.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value
    Next

    connection.Open()
    command.Connection = connection
    dataAdapter.SelectCommand = command
```

What am I missing here?  Nothing is getting inserted into my table.  Any help would be appreciated.  Like I said, I'm not very familiar with VB so take it easy on me.

Comment: `SelectCommand` and `InsertCommand` just hold the text for the select and insert query/commands, respectively. You should set `command` to be  `dataAdapter`'s `InsertCommand` and then execute the command (not sure how this works for SQL server).

Comment: Google the title of your question is my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, you need to execute the command, not simply add to the DataAdapter
Also, as it coded now, you don't need the DataAdapter at all.

```
Dim connection As New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
Dim command As New Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand

connection.ConnectionString = "Server= server; Database= DB; integrated security=true"
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO <table> (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4) VALUES (@Name, @Property, @Value, @Date)"

command.Parameters.Add("@ServerName", SqlDbType.VarChar)
command.Parameters.Add("@Property", SqlDbType.VarChar)
command.Parameters.Add("@Value", SqlDbType.VarChar)
command.Parameters.Add("@CaptureDate", SqlDbType.DateTime)
connection.Open()
command.Connection = connection

For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView.Rows.Count - 1
    command.Parameters(0).Value = dgvServerConfig.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value
    command.Parameters(1).Value = dgvServerConfig.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value
    command.Parameters(2).Value = dgvServerConfig.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value
    command.Parameters(3).Value = dgvServerConfig.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value
    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
Next
```

However this calls the database to insert one row at a time. I think it is better to look at the [SqlDataAdapter.Update](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1z2bkx2.aspx) method that resolves the insert/update work with just one call.

Using the SqlDataAdapter.Update method, requires that you save in a global variable the Adapter used at the moment in which you have filled the DataGridView and add a SqlCommandBuilder that generates for you the InsertCommand, UpdateCommand and DeleteCommand

```
    ' At form loading'
    Dim adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter()
    adapter.SelectCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT COL1, COL2,COL3,COL4 FROM TABLE", connection)
    Dim builder As OleDbCommandBuilder = New OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter)
    connection.Open()
    Dim myTable As DataTable = New DataTable
    adapter.Fill(myTable)
    DataGridView.DataSource = myTable
    ....

    ' at grid save'
    Dim myTable = CType(DataGridView.DataSource, DataTable)
    adapter.Update(myTable)
```

Comment: Steve, you are the greatest! Thank you so much for your help. Your advice and direction was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can call:  `command.ExecuteNonQuery` to insert data to the DB.

More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

Answer (score 0):

For each object in your GridView, you need to find it and determine its value. So for example,

```
DropDownList ddlToLoc = (DropDownList)gvMovesMod.Rows[0].FindControl("ddlToLoc");
```

Then, determine ddlToLoc's SelectedValue and insert to database

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS METHOD**

```
 For index As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1

            Dim connectionString = "Data Source=localhost;port=3306;Initial Catalog=hasna;User Id=root;password=''; Convert Zero Datetime=True"
            Dim query0 = "insert into itemledgerfinal(Date,BillDate,BillNo,ItemName,GST,Rate,MRP,TotalQty,PurchaseRate,WholesaleRate,Total,Type,OpeningBalance,Purchase,Sale,ClosingBalance,ID) values(@Date,@BillDate,@BillNo,@ItemName,@GST,@Rate,@MRP,@TotalQty,@PurchaseRate,@WholesaleRate,@Total,@Type,@OpeningBalance,@Purchase,@Sale,@ClosingBalance,@ID)"


            Dim connection0 As New MySqlConnection(connectionString)
            Dim command0 As New MySqlCommand(query0, connection0)


            command0.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", DataGridView1.Rows(index).Cells(0).Value)
            command0.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BillDate", DataGridView1.Rows(index).Cells(1).Value) 
            command0.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BillNo", DataGridView1.Rows(index).Cells(2).Value)
            command0.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemName", DataGridView1.Rows(index).Cells(3).Value)
            command0.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GST", DataGridView1.Rows(index).Cells(4).Value)
            command0.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rate", DataGridView1.Rows(index).Cells(5).Value)
            command0.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MRP", DataGridView1.Rows(index).Cells(6).Value)
            command0.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalQty", DataGridView1.Rows(index).Cells(7).Value)
            command0.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PurchaseRate", DataGridView1.Rows(index).Cells(8).Value)
            command0.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WholesaleRate", DataGridView1.Rows(index).Cells(9).Value)
            command0.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Total", DataGridView1.Rows(index).Cells(10).Value)
            command0.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", DataGridView1.Rows(index).Cells(11).Value)
            command0.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OpeningBalance", DataGridView1.Rows(index).Cells(12).Value)
            command0.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Purchase", DataGridView1.Rows(index).Cells(13).Value)
            command0.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sale", DataGridView1.Rows(index).Cells(14).Value)
            command0.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClosingBalance", DataGridView1.Rows(index).Cells(15).Value)
            command0.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", DataGridView1.Rows(index).Cells(16).Value)
            connection0.Open()
            command0.Connection = Connection
            command0.ExecuteNonQuery()

        Next
```

Comment: The question already has an accepted answer and your answer does not improve on it. Please read : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Thanks for that, but i searched for the code that fulfill  above task and this accepted post not helped me...when i found it...i just want to help others who just want the idea get done..leave it like that only someone will get benefit out of it. :)