# Slow get data from data gridview into SQL Server

Tags: vb.net

I have 50000 records to display on datagridview then I want save it to database, but it is very slow when inserting into SQL Server.

My code:

```
   For x As Integer = 0 To Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
                With DataGridView1
                       Insert into tbl1 values("&.Rows(x).Cells(0).Value&", ......)
                End With
   Next
```

Do you have any solutions?

Comment: Check this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16530686/vb-net-insert-datagridview-contents-into-database) might help as well

Answer (score 1):

A fast way to insert many records into an SQL Server's table is to use the **SqlBulkCopy** class.

First you will need a function which will copy the content of your DataGridView into a DataTable.

```
Private Function GetDataTable() As DataTable
    Dim DataTable1 As New DataTable

    Dim i1, i2, RowsCount1 As Integer

    For i1 = 0 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
        DataTable1.Columns.Add(DataGridView1.Columns(i1).Name, DataGridView1.Columns(i1).ValueType)
    Next

    If DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = True Then
        RowsCount1 = DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
    Else
        RowsCount1 = DataGridView1.Rows.Count
    End If

    For i1 = 0 To RowsCount1 - 1
        DataTable1.Rows.Add(DataTable1.NewRow)

        For i2 = 0 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
            DataTable1.Rows(i1).Item(i2) = DataGridView1.Rows(i1).Cells(i2).Value
        Next
    Next

    Return DataTable1
End Function
```

This DataTable will be inserted into the database by using the WriteToServer method of the SqlBulkCopy class.

The following code inserts a provided DataTable into the database.

```
Private Sub SaveToDatabase(ByVal DataTable1 As DataTable)
    Dim ConnectionStr1 As String = "Server=ServerAddress;Database=DataBaseName;User Id=Username;Password=Password;"
    Dim SqlBulkCopy1 As New SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy(ConnectionStr1)

    SqlBulkCopy1.DestinationTableName = "TableName"

    SqlBulkCopy1.ColumnMappings.Add("SourceColumn1", "DestinationColumn1")
    SqlBulkCopy1.ColumnMappings.Add("SourceColumn2", "DestinationColumn2")
    SqlBulkCopy1.ColumnMappings.Add("SourceColumn3", "DestinationColumn3")
    '
    '

    SqlBulkCopy1.WriteToServer(DataTable1)
    SqlBulkCopy1.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: 'dataType' argument cannot be null.
Parameter name: dataType

Comment: If you provide the names and the data types of your SQL Server's fields I will be able to help you. Edit your post and add them there.